# Generalising Plane Isometries to $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, transformation, transformational-geometry

Firstly, **I DO NOT WANT PROOFS OF ANY OF THESE THEOREMS**, as I wish to prove them myself. However, I would like to know the correct generalizations to $\mathbb{R}^3$ of the following theorems:

> 1. An isometry on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that fixes three non-collinear points is the identity.
> 2. An isometry on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that fixes two points is a reflection or the identity.
> 3. An isometry on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that fixes exactly one point is a product of two reflections.
> 4. Every isometry on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a product of at most three reflections.

Here are my thoughts so far:

> 1. An isometry on $\mathbb{R}^3$ that fixes four non-coplanar points is the identity.
> 2. An isometry on $\mathbb{R}^3$ that fixes three non-collinear points is a reflection or the identity.
> 3. Not so sure.
> 4. Every isometry on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a product of at most four reflections.

Comment: Upon consideration, I think that of the four non-coplanar points, no three can be collinear in order to guarantee that the isometry is the identity map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked my lecturer today, and he said that the generalizations are as follows

> 1. An isometry on $\mathbb{R}^3$ that fixes four non-coplanar points, where no three are collinear, is the identity.
> 2. An isometry on $\mathbb{R}^3$ that fixes three non-collinear points is a reflection or the identity.
> 3. An isometry on $\mathbb{R}^3$ that fixes two points is a product of at most two reflections.
> 4. Every isometry on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a product of at most four reflections.